# vercel: Error: Size of uploaded file exceeds 300MB

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, vercel, deepface

I am trying to deploy a basic python app which uses the Deepface.analyze function. When trying to deploy the app on Vercel, I get this error:

```
Size of uploaded file exceeds 300MB
```

Is it because of large libraries like deepFace and tensorflow? Or could it because of my code structure?

I have a basic python flask app with this structure:

```
static
--styles.css
templates
--index.html
app.py
requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Size of uploaded file exceeds 300MB` error message on Vercel cloud deployment platform indicates that your application exceeds Vercel's deployment size limit. Cloud platforms like Vercel cater to various programming languages. Their core functionality revolves around deployment and scaling, not specific languages.

Large libraries like DeepFace and TensorFlow are known for their large size due to pre-trained models and dependencies. Including them in your deployment package significantly increases the overall application size.